Block TODOs following waiting from agenda
I often have TODOs which are not ready to do because I am waiting on input information: I have a TODO keyword called WAITING as a reminder of what exactly I'm waiting for.
Example:
*** PROJECT Report finalised
**** WAITING updated drawings from client
**** TODO Smarten up figures
**** TODO Read over once more

I have an agenda that lists all TODOs (that are actually "TODO") and what I would like is that and TODOs which come after a WAITING do not appear on the agenda.
I make this work I am happy to simply delete the WAITING entry once I have received the drawings, in this case. Or to change the layout of these entries to fit in with a simple solution.
My workaround at the moment is to not put the keyword on the last two lines, but it makes work for me then to add them back in.

I'm a bit confused if there is a question here and if that is actually programming-related. Can you clarify?

Sorry folks: I will move my question to the emacs stackexchange!
